# Convert Array list containing Datetime to String array list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to Asp.Net and hence this question which I know might sound silly but I am really reaching no where.

Is there a way to convert an array list that contains 'Datetime' values to an array list of strings ? I wanted to use the output as a part of a javascript function.

Thanks for the help !

I am using Asp.Net with VB.

**Updated**

Here is the snippet

```
Dim timeLapse As New ArrayList
Dim timelapsehour As New ArrayList
Dim DtTmOfInf As DateTime
DtTmOfInf = DateTime.Parse(temp)
.
.
.
For i = 0 To timeLapse.Count - 1
timelapsehour.Add(DtTmOfInf.AddHours(timeLapse(i)))
  Next
```

Here the 'DtTmOfInf' stores the value of 'temp' which is a string in datetime format and the timelapsehour is that array list that stores the required date and time values.

Comment: Can you show how you build your list of `DateTime`s?

Comment: Is your object an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx), [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx), or [generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)? Note, this would have been obvious if you had posted your code instead of merely describing the problem.

Comment: I am sorry I should have posted the code. I'll edit my question to add the required part.

Comment: @Cory : I have updated the question with the code

Comment: You should start moving away from old structures like `ArrayList`. I would replace `New ArrayList` with `New List(Of DateTime)` so you have a strongly typed collection and so my answer will work for you.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment I realized my error. Thanks a lot :) I'll try in the remaining code

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a one-liner even (with Linq):

```
Dim yourDateList As List(Of DateTime) = ... 

Dim yourStringList = yourDateList.Select(Function(d) d.ToString()).ToList()
```

I've made some assumptions about your data types; if you could add to your question the code you use to build your list, then I can refine as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help but would it be wrong to write say for example ->Dim yourstringlist as arraylist = yourdatelist.Tostring().Tolist()

Comment: Sorry to trouble you but would this expression be correct if no function is being used ?                                             Dim myArr = select(timelapsehour(i).ToString()).tolist()

Comment: @Linus, no, you need to start with a collection before you can use `Select` (e.g. `list.Select(...)` or `from item in list select...`).